# Criar uma rota no Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

como faço para adaptar o script abaixo para o seguinte próposito:

*O usuário abre a página e aparece o mapa em um lugar pré-definido (empresa). Depois ele clica em um input e digita a localização dele, (o input fica acima do mapa), depois ele clica em um botao "chegar", e no mesmo instante, uma rota é traçada do ponto onde ele está, até o lugar que já estava pré-definido anteriormente. (ex: uma empresa).*

```
**Segue o código:**
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Traçar Rota</title>

        <style>

            * { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 }

            #mapa { 
                width: 940px;
                height: 400px;
                border: 10px solid #ccc;;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            /* =============== Estilos do autocomplete =============== */
            .ui-autocomplete { 
                background: #fff; 
                border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
                cursor: pointer; 
                font: 15px 'Open Sans',Arial;
                margin-left: 3px;
                position: fixed;
            }

            .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item { 
                list-style: none outside none;
                padding: 7px 0 9px 10px;
            }

            .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item:hover { background: #eee }

            .ui-autocomplete .ui-corner-all { 
                color: #666 !important;
                display: block;
            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princiweb.com.br/demos/google-maps-api-v3-busca-endereco-autocomplete/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
       <script>

        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var marker;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.898123, -48.265920);
            var options = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            marker.setPosition(latlng);

            var styles = [
            {
              stylers: [
                { hue: "#41a7d5" },
                { saturation: 60 },
                { lightness: -20 },
                { gamma: 1.51 }
              ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "road",
              elementType: "geometry",
              stylers: [
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: "simplified" }
              ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "road",
              elementType: "labels"
            }
            ];

            // crio um objeto passando o array de estilos (styles) e definindo um nome para ele;
            var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
            name: "Mapa Style"
            });

            // Aplicando as configurações do mapa
            map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
            map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            initialize();

                // CARREGANDO O MAPA
                function carregarNoMapa(endereco) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                                $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                $('#txtLatitude').val(latitude);
                                $('#txtLongitude').val(longitude);

                                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                marker.setPosition(location);
                                map.setCenter(location);
                                map.setZoom(16);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

                // CAPTURANDO AS POSIÇÕES E RESULTANDO
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {  
                                $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                $('#txtLatitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                $('#txtLongitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("#txtEndereco").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
                            response($.map(results, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.formatted_address,
                                    value: item.formatted_address,
                                    latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                                    longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                                }
                            }));
                        })
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#txtLatitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
                        $("#txtLongitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
                        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
                        marker.setPosition(location);
                        map.setCenter(location);
                        map.setZoom(16);
                    }
                });

                 $("#btnEndereco").click(function(){
                    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                    var request = {
                        origin: $("#txtEndereco").val(),
                        destination: marker.position,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("form").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var endereco = $("#txtEndereco").val();
                    var latitude = $("#txtLatitude").val();
                    var longitude = $("#txtLongitude").val();

                    alert("EndereÃ§o: " + endereco + "\nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                });

        });


    </script>

</head>

<body>      

    <form method="post" action="">    
                <fieldset>   

                    <div class="campos" style="margin: 15px;">
                        <input type="text" id="txtEndereco" name="txtEndereco" size="50" style="padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;" placeholder="Onde estou..."/>
                        <input type="button" id="btnEndereco" name="btnEndereco" value="CHEGAR" style=" padding: 15px;" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="mapa"></div>

                    <input type="hidden" type="submit" value="Enviar" name="btnEnviar" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txtLatitude" name="txtLatitude" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="txtLongitude" name="txtLongitude" />

                </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: você editou a resposta e pediu para reabrir a questão usando código fornecido numa resposta. O que está a fazer não é o correto. Se quer realmente que a questão seja reaberta, reformule a questão fornecendo mais dados do que pretende fazer, do que falta e o que está acontecendo de errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa do serviço `DirectionsService`, este você pode colocar junto das variáveis que estão no topo dos seu *script*:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

E então, no clique do botão `btnEndereco`, você pode substituir pela chamada deste serviço que consiste em iniciar o objeto de renderização das direções, criar um objeto com os parâmetros necessários para realizar a requisição e realiza-la de fato:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var request = {
        origin: $("#txtEndereco").val(),
        destination: marker.position,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }
});
```

Após concluir a requisição com sucesso, a rota será desenhada no mapa. Na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=pt-br) deste serviço você encontra mais informações, caso queira mais detalhes desta solução.

Comment: Paulo Rodrigues, eu atualizei o código. Porque não está funcionando?

Comment: Seu método `createrote()` não pode ser chamado no `onclick` do `<input>` diretamente. Coloque-o dentro do `$("#btnEndereco").click(function() {`.

Comment: Paulo Rodrigues, realizei as alterações mas o mapa não esta aparecendo....

Comment: Erro de sintaxe, faltou fechar `}` e `)`. E você chama a função de clique duas vezes. [Aqui](http://pastebin.com/JrfbndvV) um código bem formatado, só comentei o *autocomplete* que você pode voltar depois.

Comment: Paulo, realizei exatamente como me passou. Veja como ficou o script, atualizei aqui. Quando mando definir a rota, ele da meio que um "bug", veja o script... Abraços

Comment: [Aqui](http://www.riabox.com.br/mapa.htm) não tem nenhum bug. Se você usar o *autocomplete*, selecionar um endereço ele vai colocar o *pin* no mapa e pressionar o botão a rota vai ser feita do endereço do *pin* até o endereço da caixa de texto, que serão os mesmo. Se você precisa de um ponto de origem fixo, coloque-o no parâmetro `destination` no código acima.

Comment: Tipo, o código já evoluiu bastante. Mas a ideia é que, quando o usuário abrir o mapa, já vai estar em um ponto específico, no caso, uma empresa. Depois que ele digitar o local onde ele está e seleciona-lo, irá aparecer no mapa o marker de onde ele está e uma rota será traçada do local onde ele está até a empresa que foi anteriormente colocada. Ou seja, um marker irá ficar onde estou, e o outro irá ficar no lugar pré-definido, e a rota é traçada entre eles depois que o usuário seleciona o endereço de onde ele está.

Comment: Como eu disse, o parâmetro `destination` então deve ser alterado para um endereço fixo, que é o endereço da empresa que você se refere.

Comment: Como posso inserir o endereço que eu quero nesse parâmetro destination? Estou mexendo com a api a pouco tempo ainda...

Comment: É uma string: `destination: "rua tal, 12, uberlandia"`

Comment: Sim , ele está com esse caminho "destination: marker.position", preciso leva-l para um latitude específica. Como ex: (-18.898123, -48.265920);

Comment: Da mesma forma como você inicializa o mapa com um ponto específico. Use `new google.maps.LatLng(-18.898123, -48.265920);`.

Comment: Compreendo. Agora funcionou. Porém, quando digito meu endereço ele já esta definindo o meu novo local automaticamente. Eu quero que ele só faça a busca depois que eu clicar no "chegar". Mas que durante o período que eu ainda estou digitando o endereço, ele continue no lugar pré-definido, entendeu?

Comment: Onde inicia o *autocomplete*, você tem **source** e **select**. Remova a execução do **select**.

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Funcionou perfeitamente, você é ótimo, cara! Outra coisa, quando realizo a busca ele está mostrando dois pontos (A e B) de rotas, mas anteriormente, eu coloquei um símbolo personalizado, e quando as rotas são mostradas, eles ficam em cima. Como na imagem: http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_rota.png . Como faço para personalizar o mesmo ícone para as duas rotas, e "sumir" co messes icones de rota A e B. Ou personalizar uma para a rota A e outra para a rota B?